# dependencies reference nonexistent parent node error when migrate in django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a project in which when I try to migrate in django, error shows as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 63, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 321, in build_graph
    _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 291, in _reraise_missing_dependency
    raise exc
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration reviews.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'catalogue', u'0001_initial')
```

I understand the problem but I'm unable to solve it.

I deleted all `.pyc` files and migration folder.

I also deleted database also but this problem persist.
How can I get rid off this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -6):

Remove migrations folder from app, also remove database and create database again. Then try with:

1. 1) python manage.py makemigrations
2. 2) python manage.py migrate

Comment: Note to anyone reading this: do NOT, NEVER "remove migration folder" from any app. This will screw any instance of any project using your app that has had previous migrations applied...

Comment: I'm agree to @brunodesthuilliers . Note everyone  Please don't follow this approach. There is only issue of not found of reference file no need to delete the migration folder or database either.

for more details about this issue pls chk https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829887/2028957

Comment: I second above opinions. My project got completely destroyed by django-parler and since my initial research showed that deleting migrations was the way to go, I tried that. Result: My whole project is now stuck on a broken migration. The worst is that python does not tell me WHERE this reference is coming from, so I will have to start from scratch!