# dependencies reference nonexistent parent node error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

So, I am learning Django using **Django By Example** book.
I moved to a new chapter where I needed to make a new project and app. This is what I did.

```
django-admin startproject myshop
```

cd to myshop directory

```
django-admin startapp shop
python manage.py migrate
```

I am unable to migrate with the following error:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0009_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'account', u'0002_contact')

I did make **Contact** model in **account** app in my last project.
How is the new project related to the old one?

Please help me resolve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You did run command `python manage.py makemigrations`, right?

Comment: Please check the error it says in **auth.0009_user** file there is block says dependencies you need to remove the reference **0002_contact. However manually doing changes is not recommended, this only for the issue fix at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have the file **0002_contact** in your **account** app's **migration** folder. You need to recover the file or configure this file  *0009_user_following* and remove the  **(u'account', u'0002_contact')** line

Comment: can you please help me understand the relation between the projects? What this means is that I will not be able to make any new project until I resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it's possible